# Using BootstrapValidator with MVC DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am using `DataAnnotations` to specify my validation rules and by default, these validation rules are added on the client side for them to be validated by jquery.

I'd like to use *BootstrapValidator.js* since I like the way the error/success messages get rendered. However, it requires me to redefine the validation rules on the client side. [An article about BootstrapValidator.js](http://www.devcurry.com/2014/08/validate-form-using-jquery-and_5.html) can be found.

Is there a way I can use `DataAnnotations` and define the rules in a single place and still use BootstrapValidator?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

No need to redefine validation rules again. You can simply integrate **MVC type validation** (which is [Jquery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org)) with Bootstrap styling by dropping a quick script and reference it after your MVC validation scripts:

```
$(function () {
    $('span.field-validation-valid, span.field-validation-error').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('help-inline');
    });

    $('.validation-summary-errors').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('alert');
        $(this).addClass('alert-error');
        $(this).addClass('alert-block');
    });

    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(this).find('div.control-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length == 0) {
                    $(this).removeClass('error');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('div.control-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                    $(this).addClass('error');
                }
            });
            $('.validation-summary-errors').each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('alert-error') == false) {
                    $(this).addClass('alert');
                    $(this).addClass('alert-error');
                    $(this).addClass('alert-block');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('form').each(function () {
        $(this).find('div.control-group').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
            }
        });
    });

    $("input[type='password'], input[type='text']").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('input-validation-error') == true || $(this).closest(".control-group").find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            $(this).closest(".control-group").removeClass("error");
        }
    });
});

var page = function () {
    //Update that validator
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest(".control-group").removeClass("error");
        }
    });
} ();
```